# Inverting a matrix expressed with summation notation

Tags: matrices, summation, inverse, gaussian-integral

I have a matrix which I can write

$$A_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \xi^2 q_i q_j$$

which I wish to invert. I know the result is

$$A_{ij}^{-1} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{q_i q_j}{q^2 + \xi^{-2}}$$

I can easily verify that this is correct, but I don't know how to get this result from the original matrix.

Comment: Maybe you can use the adjoint matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Dirac's [Braket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) helps. In that form your operator $A$ can be written as $$A = 1 + \xi^2 \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert.$$

Now $\langle q | q \rangle = \lVert q \rVert^2$ so for $k \geq 1$ you get $$\left(\lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert\right)^k = \lVert q \rVert^{2(k-1)} \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert.$$

For small $\xi$ the inverse can now be written down as a geometric series:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\left(1 + \xi^2 \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert\right)^{-1} &=& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\xi^2 \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert\right)^k \\
&=& 1 +\lVert q \rVert^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\xi^2 \lVert q \rVert^2)^k \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert \\
&=& 1 - \xi^2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-\xi^2 \lVert q \rVert^2)^k \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert \\
&=& 1 - \xi^2\frac1{1+\xi^2 \lVert q \rVert^2} \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert \\
&=& 1 - \frac1{\xi^{-2}+\lVert q \rVert^2} \lvert q\rangle \langle q \rvert
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: What if $\xi$ cannot be assumed to be small? In my case $\xi$ is a correlation length which diverges at low temperatures.

Comment: @Kai Like you said, once you have this inverse determined for some $\xi$ it is not hard to check that it is always correct. Alternatively, since $q$ is an eigenvector and $q^{\perp}$ is pointwise fixed the inverse must be of the form $1+\alpha |q\rangle \langle q|$. Then determine $\alpha$.